# What is the opposite of "aegrescit medendo"?

Tags: idiom, vergilius

There is a well-known Latin phrase, *aegrescit medendo*, which means, "worsens with treatment". I believe it comes from Virgil (correct me if I am wrong). I wanted to know if there is an attested phrase which means the opposite, i.e. "improves with treatment". Is there such a phrase? If not, what would be the best way to formulate this in Latin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reference from Virgil is to Aeneid XII, 46, *aegrescitque medendo* (in the combat between Aeneas and Turnus).

The opposite is easily and exactly rendered as *convalescit medendo*. There may not be a positive attestation, but use of the verb is well supported.

Comment: Thanks for locating the phrase. Your suggestion has a nice sound to it and is easily understandable.